# Laravel Valet/Nginx: 502 Bad Gateway: 93883#0: *613 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1

Tags: laravel, nginx, valet

I've tried increasing the buffer sizes as suggested in other threads. Here is the output of

```
sudo nginx -T | grep buffer
```

```
fastcgi_buffer_size 4096k;
fastcgi_buffers 128 4096k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 4096k;
proxy_buffer_size   4096k;
proxy_buffers   128 4096k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   4096k;
```

I've restarted valet but I am still getting the error when submitting a POST request after adding something to my cart using darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Still having this problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was? I’m having the same issue, albeit with [a different LaravelShoppingCart library](https://github.com/bumbummen99/LaravelShoppingcart/). I get the same “upstream sent too big header” error if I try to return a view or redirect after doing anything cart-related beyond listing the contents, like adding an item or restoring the cart from the database.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this same error from my local Drupal 9 site. I've spent a few hours myself trying to find a solution that actually works for Valet (plus). After some trial and error the following steps solved the problem for me. Hope this helps anyone facing the same issue:

1. go to the nginx config folder:

   ```
   cd /usr/local/etc/nginx
   ```
2. edit the nginx.conf file:

   ```
   sudo nano nginx.conf
   ```
3. add these lines to the http{} section and save the file:
   **proxy_buffer_size 4096k;

   proxy_buffers 128 4096k;

   proxy_busy_buffers_size 4096k;**

   ```
   http {
       include mime.types;
       default_type  application/octet-stream;

       proxy_buffer_size 4096k;
       proxy_buffers 128 4096k;
       proxy_busy_buffers_size 4096k;

       sendfile on;
       tcp_nopush on;
       tcp_nodelay on;
       ...
   ```
4. edit the fastcgi_params file:

   ```
   sudo nano fastcgi_params
   ```
5. append these lines to the end of the file:
   **fastcgi_buffer_size 4096k;

   fastcgi_buffers 128 4096k;

   fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 4096k;**

   ```
   fastcgi_param HTTPS   $https if_not_empty;
   fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS  200;
   fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY  "";
   fastcgi_buffer_size 4096k;
   fastcgi_buffers 128 4096k;
   fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 4096k;
   ```
6. restart valet:

   ```
   valet restart
   ```
7. Refresh the site in your browser